# How to get this "Create New Team Project" dialog in TFS?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

In this article about [Getting Started with Git in Visual Studio and Team Foundation Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx), they show these screenshots of the "New Team Project" dialog(s):

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-45-92-2013-01-Getting+Started+with+Git/1373.NewGitProject.png
http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-45-92-2013-01-Getting+Started+with+Git/4370.NewGitProject2.png

However, I can't find that first dialog, and when I go to "New Team Project" in Visual Studio, my dialog looks like this:

[image]

And if I go through it all, once I get to where I can pick the type of source control, I only get one option:

[image]

Where is it/what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, what you get is correct.

The first two screenshots shows how to create team project hosted in Visual Studio Team Services in IE.  Check this link for the details about Team Services: (https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs)

However, what you tries is to create one team project hosted in on-premise TFS in VS. Additionally, if you would like to set the Version Control to Git, you need to upgrade your TFS server to TFS2013 or above.